# Laravel 5.1 auth system with status

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

I am new to laravel I have integrated inbuilt authentication system and works perfect. Now I also want to consider status field of user table while authenticate. I search a lot but could not find proper way to integrate such functionality with inbuilt laravel's authentication system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering user status when authenticating is simple. There are 2 ways to do that, depending whether you call **Auth::attempt()** manually or you use **AuthenticatesUsers** or **RegistersAndAuthenticatesUsers** trait in your controller.

If you are calling **Auth::attempt()** manually, you always pass an array of credentials to the method. Those credentials are used to fetch user from the database. Add **status** field to those credentials and only users with given status will be able to log in, e.g.:

```
Auth::attempt([
    'username' => Request::input('username'),
    'password' => Request::input('password'),
    'status'   => 'active'
]);
```

Above will allow only users with **status=active** to log in.

If you are using **AuthenticatesUsers** or **RegistersAndAuthenticatesUsers** trait in your controller, you need to override the **getCredentials()** method. This method should return the same array that you'd pass to **Auth::attempt()**:

```
 protected function getCredentials(Request $request) {
  return [
    'username' => Request::input('username'),
    'password' => Request::input('password'),
    'status'   => 'active'
  ];
}
```

Comment: it works thanks, Is there any way to add something like ['deleted' => NULL]

Comment: Not really, as the UserProvider internally calls where($field, '=', $value) which won't work with NULL values, as that would require whereNotNull($field) to be called. But instead of implementing soft delete yourself make use of SoftDeletes trait in your user model and this will work with Laravel authetication - users with deleted_at won't be able to log in.